# Debian GNU\Linux Time Differences

Tags: time, date, time-zone

i'm trying to find out why my linux have this difference in times:

cmd1: date

out1: Sun 14 Jul 2019 12:45:59 AM CDT

cmd2: hwclock

out2: 2019-07-14 00:46:48.389904-04:00

cmd3: timedatectl

out3:

```
Local time: Sun 2019-07-14 01:47:17 -03 [correct time!]

Universal time: Sun 2019-07-14 04:47:17 UTC

RTC time: Sun 2019-07-14 04:47:17

Time zone: America/Montevideo (-03, -0300)

System clock synchronized: yes

NTP service: active

RTC in local TZ: no
```

I was used Debian Strech with Awesome WM with the same problem, now in Debian Buster with i3...same problem.

Help please!

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `~/.profile`:

```
TZ='America/Montevideo'; export $TZ
```